# python need help on attributes for builtin command os

Tags: python

I need to know how to use help in python to check what each attribute does on the os builtin in python 
for example:`dir(os)
['CLD_CONTINUED', 'CLD_DUMPED', 'CLD_EXITED', 'CLD_TRAPPED', 'EX_CANTCREAT', 'EX_CONFIG', 'EX_DATAERR', 'EX_IOERR', 'EX_NOHOST', 'EX_NOINPUT', 'EX_NOPERM', 'EX_NOUSER', 'EX_OK', 'EX_OSERR', 'EX_OSFILE', 'EX_PROTOCOL', 'EX_SOFTWARE', 'EX_TEMPFAIL', 'EX_UNAVAILABLE', .....so on`

how to check what the attribute `os.getcwd()` is for

Comment: or the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os

Answer (score 1):

You can use help command which shows the docstring for any object or method

```
help(os.getcwd)
```

It is little bit similar to man command in unix. For detail info, you can check out the documentation of `os` command - [os command documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)